# CentOS 5, cannot accept htaccess

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, htaccess

I have problem with htaccess on my vps.I installed CentOS 5, uploaded site on /var/www/html and it works.But, htaccess isn't working.I tried to add AllowOverride All in httpd.conf, also uncomment Loadmodule rewrite...I tried to add "deny from all" but no success.It normally loads site..

What can I do ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure AccessFileName set to .htaccess**

Search httpd.conf for AccessFileName directive. It defines name of the distributed configuration file:

```
grep -i AccessFileName httpd.conf
```

**Make sure users are allowed to use .htaccess file**

What you can put in these files is determined by the AllowOverride directive. This directive specifies, in categories, what directives will be honored if they are found in a .htaccess file. If this directive is set to None, then .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.

```
grep -i AllowOverride httpd.conf
```

When this directive is set to All, then any directive which has the .htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess files:

```
AllowOverride ALL
```

Save and close the file. Restart httpd:

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: Here's log :
[code]
[root@srv1 ~]# grep -i AccessFileName /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
AccessFileName .htaccess

[root@srv1 ~]# grep -i AllowOverride /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    AllowOverride All
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    AllowOverride None
#    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
    AllowOverride None
    AllowOverride None
        AllowOverride None

Comment: Still nothing..